# How to expand column inside a row

Tags: flutter

I'm apologise to do this question again but I was reading similar ones and try to solve my problen and Iwasn't able to fix it.
I need my column(blue one) inside row expands vertically to and have the max heigth.
Here is my code

```
   Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Card(
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: ListTile(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
              title: AutoSizeText('text',
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
              subtitle: AutoSizeText(
                'subText',
                maxLines: 1,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            )),
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  child: FaIcon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.locationDot,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Edited: Added expected output
[image: Expected ouput]

Comment: Could you add your expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter expand column inside row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822182/flutter-expand-column-inside-row)

Comment: Soory, I write the wrong code, please check it again

Answer (score 0):

remove following line from the **column** widget

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and replace my widget code to your

```
Container(
      height: 70,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListTile(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
              title: Text('text',
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
              subtitle: Text(
                'subText',
                maxLines: 1,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 70,
                width: 70,
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: Thanks, but you have a fixed height. I need non fixed height because Listile can expand if it has a lot of text